# Sub-query with an inequality operator, and a strongly correlated sub-query

Tags: sql

[list of all salaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmChP.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfdxF.png)1. a)

Sub-query with an inequality operator, and a weakly correlated sub-query.

Write a SQL query that shows the empno, ename, job and total salary for all employees from the emp table, and uses a sub-query to show that earn more than the average salary. You will have to times sal by 52 weeks plus the commission *12 (commission is paid on a monthly basis) in the outer query and in the inner query (sub-query) to get the correct amounts, assuming that the value in sal represents the pay for one week.

1.b)
Sub-query with an inequality operator, and a strongly correlated sub-query.

Write a SQL query that shows the empno, ename, job and total salary for all employees from the emp table and uses a sub-query to show employees that earn more than the average salary per job, because the first query compared everyone to the overall average, now we want to break it down by job.
Format the salary returned in the result set using the to_char() function to display the numbers in the currency format. You will have to account for a six-figure salary because they are all big earners.

My code from the 1st part of the query, returns correctly.  I'm not sure how to get part b to return correctly.:

```
empno, ename, job, to_char(sal*52+12*(nvl(comm, 0)),'$999,999')as total_salary
from emp
where sal*52+12*(nvl(comm, 0)) > (select avg(sal*52+12*(nvl(comm, 0)))from emp);
```

Comment: There is no question here, only statement. What is your question? Show your **complete** SQL, not an extract from it. Check out [ask]

Comment: I think if you can't do simple homework like this you should drop the class.  We certainly can't do it for you if you don't give us the data model and other material needed to solve these problems.  (Test data)

Comment: Imagine that someone wrote a really nice but long solution query, took a screenshot of it, and added that image as an answer, would you be annoyed about the transcription effort? **Please don't use images of data**, just copy/paste some data into the question and format it using the `{}` button in the toolbar.